# Paste text to a jupyter notebook cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook, paste

I am new to Jupyter Notebook --I am using Anaconda 3 with Windows 7 and Internet Explorer-- and I have been trying to paste text that I copied from a text file into a Jupyter notebook cell (I.e. some code). However when I right click my mouse, the pop-up window that appears does not list copy and paste options but rather the following:

- Back
- Search using copied text
- Select all All
- Accelerator
- Create shortcuts
- Add to favorites
- View source
- Inspect element
- Encoding
- Print
- Print Preview
- Refresh
- Export to Excel
- Send to One Note
- Properties.

I have tried the shortcut control V and it does not work.  Moreover, I tried opening the Jupyter Notebook with Chrome and again I don't see the copy - paste options.

I run the Jupyter notebook by typing 'ipython notebook' in Windows Commander.

So my question is: what should I do to paste text into my Jupyter Notebook cell?

Regarding the version of Jupyter Notebook:

About Jupyter Notebook
Server Information:

You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is 4.3.1 and is running on:
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Current Kernel Information:

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: A screen shot may be helpful.

Comment: I tried to take a screen shot but to do that I have to click on the keyboard and then the pop up windows disappears.  However the list above is an accurate depictions of the options appearing in Internet explorer.

Comment: Do you know what version of Jupyter you are running? There was a known bug in `term.js`: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/104

Comment: I added relevant information to my question.